# controlling form elements from a class in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, user-interface

I created this custom test class:

```
#include "Form1.h"

class Demo
{
public:
    void sayHello()
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::Form1->Text = "Hello Form!"; // does not work
        Form1->Text = "Hello Form!"; // does not work
        Form1.Text = "Hello Form!"; // does not work
    }
};
```

I essentially get this compiler error:

```
c:\users\pieter kubben\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testclassref\testclassref\Demo.h(8): error C2065: 'Form1' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\pieter kubben\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testclassref\testclassref\Demo.h(8): error C2227: left of '->Text' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

So I guess it does not see Form1. The other way around, so have the `sayHello()` function called when clicking the button in Form1, is no problem.

I noticed that my `main()` function (auto-generated by the IDE) contains this line:
`Application::Run(gcnew Form1());`

So it looks to me that Form1 has not yet been created when the compiler starts, although Form1.h does exist (of course).

How can I access Form1 elements from my custom class? E.g. change Form1.Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global variable to hold your form object and alter the IDE generated to show the form
like this

```
Form1 frm=gvnew Form1();
Application::Run(frm);
```

Now frm is the referecne fo the form1 class and you can access it to access the Form1 class members. If you want to access frm object outside of the Main function then declare a global variable and access it.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I try that code (of course using `gcnew` instead of `gvnew`) then the Visual C++ compiler tells me that Form1 has no copy constructor. If I put in a handle, so typing `Form1^ lynxMoveForm = gcnew Form1();` I get an error C3145: `'lynxMoveForm' : global or static variable may not have managed type 'LynxMoveCLI::Form1 ^'`.

Comment: Addition: will try with `Form1^ lynxMoveForm = gcnew Form1;` and see if that works. There seems to be another problem with referring to `Form1.h` from my class, the compiler goes crazy telling me that I redefine all kind of stuff. Will look at that first.

Answer (score 0):

```
error C3145: 'form' : global or static variable may not have managed type
```

This is what I get, when you try to make global variable of form like `Form1 ^frm;` or `Form1 ^frm = gcnew Form1();`

So I created container to it, which worked fine to me. 
There is an example

```
ref class FormContainer{
public:
    static MyForm ^form;
};
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    FormContainer::form = gcnew MyForm();
    Application::Run(FormContainer::form);
}
```

Now u can get access to form public members, so be sure to make getters and setters you need.

```
void SayHello(){
  FormContainer::form->label1->Text = "Hello";
}
```

P.S. I am using VS 2013.